# $\langle x,y\rangle = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T} x(t)\overline{y(t)}\, dt$ is not separable

Tags: functional-analysis

> Consider the family of exponential functions $S = \{e_\lambda
>  \}_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}}$, where $e_\lambda : \mathbb{R} →
>  \mathbb{C}, e_{\lambda}(t) = e^{i\lambda t}$ and let $H_0 ⊆
> C^0(\mathbb{R})$ be the linear subspace generated by $S$. If $x, y \in
>  H_0$, define 
>     $$\langle x,y\rangle = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T}
>  x(t)\overline{y(t)} \,dt$$ 
>   Show that $H_0$ is not separable

Hi, I have to prove two things, first : $H_0$ is an inner product, and I have it. 
But, I know that I have to find a subset of it that is not countable dense, and this is my problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The set $\{ e_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}}$ forms an (uncountable) orthonormal family. Why is this a problem? (further hint, examine the distance between elements in this family).

Comment: sorry but i can't show it. can you give an example, please?

Comment: Did you compute the distances between $e_{\lambda_1}$ and $e_{\lambda_2}$ for $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$?

Comment: yes, is $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Now suppose you have a countable dense subset. Fix a delta smaller than $\sqrt{2}/2$, then there is a different element from this countable set near each of these undoubtably many elements. That’s impossible by counting